# Decorate all properties with type metadata in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, reflection, types, metadata

Given this code:

```
class Foo {
    text: String;
}
```

TypeScript will produce this JavaScript:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
}());
```

But if I decorate `text` with any decorator, such as `function bar(t, k) {}` like this:

```
class Foo {
    @bar text: String;
}
```

TypeScript will produce:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    __decorate([
        bar, 
        __metadata('design:type', String)
    ], Foo.prototype, "text", void 0);
    return Foo;
}());
```

That is, it decorates `text` with the `bar` function *and* with `design:type` metadata. This is great, but I'd like to instruct TypeScript to decorate *all* properties with `design:type` metadata, without the need of a bogus decorator like `@bar`.

Is it possibile in the latest TypeScript? If not (see comments) any suggestions on how to use the Compiler API to achieve this?

Comment: No. The decorators are still "an experimental feature that may change in future releases" so using it to begin with is at your "own risk". And there's no compilation flag to say that "all properties should be metadataed". You can probably do that if you use the compiler as service and then do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you @NitzanTomer I understand all that is experimental, but I'd like to find a way to instruct the compiler to add type metadata to all properties for my projects. Do you have suggestion on how plug-in this functionality?

Comment: As I wrote, you can use [the compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) to do it yourself. I haven't played with it myself, but you will probably need to use the AST and change it so that every property is decorated with `@Reflect.metadata("design:type", PROPERTY_TYPE)`.